# Overriding the redirect on saving force:createRecord on Salesforce Lightning

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I need to override the redirect on save of a force:createRecord lightning component.

```
var eve = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
eve.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        "AccountId" : accountId
    },  
    "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
        console.log('test');
        //console.log(event.getParam("id"));
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "<some visualforce page url>",
            "isredirect": "true"
        }); 
        urlEvent.fire();
    }   
});
eve.fire();
```

Comment: You should add a language-specific tag to increase the visibility of your question.

Comment: @val you'll want to post this to salesforce.stackexchange.com